# Alternative way to run a query with join

Tags: sql, impala

I have the below query:

```
select m.name, m.surname,m.teacher,
c.classroom,c.floor
from table1 as m 
inner join table2 as c
on (m.name=c.name or m.surname = c.surname);
```

But it takes a lot of time to execute the query. I want to ask if there is any other alternative way of running it.

Also the rows that query tried to fetched were ~47b, before I stopped it.

This result is reasonably if the query did cross join not inner join as it does.

Each table has 14m rows.

Comment: 47B rows is a lot, how do you propose to optimize that? What are your indexes? Better question, what are you doing that requires 47B rows

Comment: @Charlieface I am performing the above query where each table has 14m as I mentioned. I want to join the tables on the columns that you see in the query but with an 'or'. I am afraid that this 'or' is the 'multiplier'.

Comment: Even 14m rows is a lot, what do you need to **do** with these rows? And how do you want to show them? Yes, you may get duplicates, but that is what your query demands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a join query with **OR** operator causes none-optimal execution plan for DBMS.

Try this:

```
select m.name, m.surname,m.teacher,c.classroom,c.floor 
from table1 m inner join table2 as c 
on m.name = c.name 
UNION
select m.name  , m.surname,m.teacher,c.classroom,c.floor
from table1 m inner join table2 as c 
on m.surname = c.surname
```

Consider that you must declare indexes on name and surname  on both tables

Answer (score 1):

`OR`s in `ON` clauses really slow things down.  You can use two `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select m.name, m.surname, m.teacher,
       coalesce(cn.classroom, cs.classroom) as classroom,
       coalesce(cn.floor, cs.floor) as floor
from table1 m left join
     table2 cn
     on m.name = cn.name left join
     table2 cs
     on m.surname = cs.surname
where cn.name is not null or cs.surname is not null
```

Comment: To tell you the truth I was about to use UNION. Select....on....UNION....Select.....on. But I will try yours approach and I will come back to you. Thanks :)